# Browser remembers form state after a refresh. How to avoid?

Tags: html, forms

Often times a browser will remember the form-state when the refresh button is hit. This is troublesome, because I actually want the updated database state to be shown when a user hits refresh.

Is there a way I can trick the browser to not remember the current form state?

Comment: I suppose you have tried the Response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache") and also the autocomplete off on the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
//Set no caching
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Brute force!

Comment: I would say use Javascript to bind the form data after the page has loaded, rather than binding it on the server side.